# check the values in many cells in one sheet

Tags: excel, function

I have two sheets in Excel.
On one sheet I would like to have a function which validates the second sheet.

Attached screenshot for better understanding:
[image: Example of what I am requesting]

**EDIT**: I am using it like this and it works: =IF(AND(ISBLANK(ABS!P4),ISBLANK(ABS!P35),ISBLANK(ABS!P38),ISBLANK(ABS!P43),ISBLANK(ABS!P49),ISBLANK(ABS!P53),ISBLANK(ABS!P54),ISBLANK(ABS!P55),ISBLANK(ABS!P71),ISBLANK(ABS!P76),ISBLANK(ABS!P77),"Not Done","Done")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `COUNTBLANK()` function like this:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!A1:A10)>0,"No","Yes")
```

Comment: Marc, the second sheet has cell which skips... like I have P04 and then P12 and then P48 and all the way to P148 but has cell which skips numbers. How do I set that? Can I use like =IF(COUNTBLANK(ABS!P4,P8,P16,P28)>0,"No","Yes") *ABS is the name of the sheet

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Sounds like your screenshot didn't provide better understanding if it doesn't represent what you're working on.  There are a number of ways to use `COUNTBLANK` in this fashion, including adding multiple `COUNTBLANK` results together.  If you're only looking at individual cells, you could use `ISBLANK` or work `SUMIF` into a more complicated construct of `COUNTBLANK`.  It's just not clear what you're looking for.  I'd encourage you to get familiar with the functions I mentioned and try to apply them to your need.

Comment: That will work. But I was referring to the cell count. I can't use A1:A10 because it's not going from A1 to A10. My cells skips in between like for example, A1 then the next cell is A8 and A12. etc etc

Comment: I updated my question with the solution I am using based off your feedback and my research. not completely efficient but gets the job done. :)

Comment: You could create a [named range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) that just includes the cells you are interested in, and then use Marc's CountBlank formula on that named range.

Comment: Doug and Marc Thanks... the Named Range did the trick along with ISBLANK

Comment: One issue now is whenever I make one of the cell blank the value does not update for the ISBLANK statement